# Are level requirements enforced in DS3 with a password?

Tags: bloodborne, dark-souls-3

In bloodborne, if you set a password you could summon or be summoned by someone with the same password, regardless of level difference.

I've only seen this mentioned as being possible in ds3 on one sight out of numerous i've encountered.  However, yesterday I was not successful in my friend finding my summon sign on a much higher level character using a password.  I know we were able to group with the password, as I was able to jump on my lower level character and he'd find me immediately (with the same password).

Has anyone had experience with this?  Are you able to group with a password regardless of level difference?  Could I have just had bad luck with this attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no level boundaries with password matchmaking.

In case of significant level difference player with high level will be nerfed (blue sign will appear near nickname).

I've faced similar issues with not being able to summon friend - see [Can I increase chances of coop with friends in Dark Souls 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/262595/144891)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't able to find a question like this when i searched.  Don't yet have the reputation on this network to create tags, or I would have used a "coop" or "online" or "cooperative" tag (or something)

Comment: still have not had any luck trying to join a low level friends game :(

Comment: It's interesting... I have ***never*** been successfully summoned for Darkmoone either.  I wonder if there's something related?

Answer (score 2):

There are no requirements besides the passwords matching. You can both be any level and the summoner, of course, must be Embered. It is also highly suggested that you turn on "Enable Global Matchmaking" (the setting directly above it.) It is believed that it is actually "Enable *Cross-Server* matchmaking." It still might take a second but with those two things you should be able to find each other.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, From Soft acknowledged the summoning issues and stated the following:

> "Password matching done under the following conditions may result in an extended amount of time required for the match to complete.
>
> Many players are signed in the corresponding area. There is a large gap between the levels of the players who are using the password.”

See on [VG247](https://www.vg247.com/2016/04/18/dark-souls-3-patch-1-04-notes/)